# How to echo value input type text when use ajax upload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to echo value input type text when use ajax upload ?

This is my code for upload file to dir `attachments_files` and it's work good.

But i have some issue. I want to know how to echo value from `id="username_uploader"` in `upload.php` using php ?

i tried to use like this

```
echo $_POST['username_uploader'];
```

but not work. Please help me .

index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="username_uploader" type="text" name="username_uploader" value="test_user"/>
<input id="attachment_file_input_id" type="file" name="sortpic" onchange="test_fn()"/>
<div id="demoajax"></div>
<script>
function test_fn () {
            var file_data = $('#attachment_file_input_id').prop('files')[0];   
            var form_data = new FormData();                  
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                        url: 'upload.php',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: form_data,                         
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(php_script_response){
                        alert("upload success");
                        $('#demoajax').append(php_script_response);
                    }
            });
};
</script>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else 
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "attachments_files/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        echo $_POST['username_uploader'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `username_uploader` value in the `FormData` you send, as you currently omit it. Try this:

```
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('username_uploader', $('#username_uploader').val());
```

It would also be better practice for your PHP code to return JSON, that way you don't need to worry about the formatting or whitespace in the returned value. Here's a complete example:

```
function test_fn () {
    var form_data = new FormData();          
    form_data.append('file', $('#attachment_file_input_id').prop('files')[0]);
    form_data.append('username_uploader', $('#username_uploader').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',                      
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,   
        success: function(response){
            alert("upload success");
            $('#demoajax').append(response.uploader);
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<?php
    if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>'));
    }
    else 
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "attachments_files/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"]);    
        echo json_encode(array('uploader' => $_POST['username_uploader']));
    }
?>
```